# Gnereta oauth token - log user information

Tags: logging, oauth, wso2, token, apim

is it possible to log information about which user is trying to generate an oauth token? I would like to see user login or consumerKey. I know that the login can be seen in the audit.log file when the user generates the token via grant type password. Is this possible with grant type client_credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following configuration to the API Manager deployment.toml

```
[event.default_listener.oauth_listener]
priority= 12
enable = true
```

Additionally add the following configurations to the log4j2.properties file in repository/conf location.

1. Add the following appender and logger

   appender.TRANSACTION_LOGFILE.type = RollingFile
   appender.TRANSACTION_LOGFILE.name = TRANSACTION_LOGFILE
   appender.TRANSACTION_LOGFILE.fileName = ${sys:carbon.home}/repository/logs/transaction.log
   appender.TRANSACTION_LOGFILE.filePattern = ${sys:carbon.home}/repository/logs/transaction-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.%i.log
   appender.TRANSACTION_LOGFILE.layout.type = PatternLayout
   appender.TRANSACTION_LOGFILE.layout.pattern = [%d] - %mm %n
   appender.TRANSACTION_LOGFILE.policies.type = Policies
   appender.TRANSACTION_LOGFILE.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
   appender.TRANSACTION_LOGFILE.policies.time.interval = 1
   appender.TRANSACTION_LOGFILE.policies.time.modulate = true
   appender.TRANSACTION_LOGFILE.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
   appender.TRANSACTION_LOGFILE.policies.size.size=10MB
   appender.TRANSACTION_LOGFILE.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
   appender.TRANSACTION_LOGFILE.strategy.max = 20
   appender.TRANSACTION_LOGFILE.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
   appender.TRANSACTION_LOGFILE.threshold.level = INFO

   logger.TRANSACTION_LOGGER.name=TRANSACTION_LOGGER
   logger.TRANSACTION_LOGGER.level=INFO
   logger.TRANSACTION_LOGGER.appenderRef.TRANSACTION_LOGFILE.ref = TRANSACTION_LOGFILE

   logger.DELETE_EVENT_LOGGER.name=DELETE_EVENT_LOGGER
   logger.DELETE_EVENT_LOGGER.level=INFO
   logger.DELETE_EVENT_LOGGER.appenderRef.TRANSACTION_LOGFILE.ref = TRANSACTION_LOGFILE
2. Add TRANSACTION_LOGFILE as appender.
3. Add TRANSACTION_LOGGER and DELETE_EVENT_LOGGER as loggers.

Sample log line:

```
[2023-01-09 19:52:11,537]  INFO - TRANSACTION_LOGGER Type: OAUTH TOKEN | Info: {"expires_in_seconds":3600,"grant_type":"client_credentials","success":true,"time_taken_in_millis":128,"type":"oauth","issued_time":1673274131530,"user":"admin@carbon.super","client_id":"SWxioTfcxLBsZobPbs29hjxhTLUa"}
```

Refer https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/guides/access-delegation/oauth-transaction-logs/